# Sort todos in agenda todo list view in reversed order

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When I call org-agenda and further strike t invoke org-todo-list,

All the todos are sorted by ascending order on the last modification time of files where they reside.

So the latest task in the latest modified file will be place to the bottom of the buffer.

Is it possible to sort them in reverse order? that is:

org-capture then call org-todo-list, and all tasks are sorted by reversed order of the modification time of file they locate.

`org-agenda-sorting-strategy-selected` is `nil`, but
`org-agenda-sorting-strategy` is

```
 ((agenda habit-down time-up priority-down category-keep)  
  (todo priority-down category-keep)  
  (tags priority-down category-keep)  
  (search category-keep))
```

The display of todo-list now is:

```
filename
2021-01   TODO:...
2021-02   TODO:...
2021-03   TODO:...
Today     TODO:...
```

and the desired look I want:

```
Today     TODO:...
2021-03   TODO:...
2021-02   TODO:...
2021-01   TODO:...
```

I tried to changed filename or categories but such efforts do not alter the sorting.

Comment: What is the value of `org-agenda-sorting-strategy-selected`?

Comment: `org-agenda-sorting-strategy-selected` is `nil`, but `org-agenda-sorting-strategy` is  `((agenda habit-down time-up priority-down category-keep)
 (todo priority-down category-keep)
 (tags priority-down category-keep)
 (search category-keep))
`

Comment: I don't think that the last modification time of files makes any difference to any sorting that Org mode does (In agenda, todo list etc): what it uses are timestamps of various kinds as found in the file, priorities, alphabetic sorting of tags and categories - the only exception is  user-defined sorting functions, but I assume you don't have any of those. So the todo list sorting strategy is `priority-down category-keep`.  So there are buckets for each category and priority combination and within each bucket, the TODOs are sorted  as they were in the file from which they came, I believe; ...

Comment: ... so given that, I'm not sure what you are seeing and what you want done. Maybe a short example ( two categories, two priorities, a few TODO entries) of how it looks now, and how you want it to look, might help.

Comment: @NickD ty very much for the patient and tutorial, I append the desired display to the question.